# Possible to Disable redis-cache plugin via config or otherwise?

Tags: grails, caching, redis

I've been testing out the cache and redis-cache plugins and there is a way to disable the cache plugin with:

```
grails.cache.enabled=false
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be able to do the same for the redis-cache plugin. So when I disabled cache, the redis-cache plugin complains about a missing bean. Seems legit, but I'd really like to be able to disable all caching for local development. Suggestions?

Comment: as of now, the killswitch for it just has a `TODO` in the plugin config.  you might be better off toggling it on/off via `BuildConfig`

Comment: Can you give me a bit more info on how to do that? And if you make it an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: if @cfrick doesn't post the example for doing so in BuildConfig I can as well. I'm sure he's just busy ;)

Comment: I'll take whatever answer I can get at this point. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, the killswitch in the plugin is just not implemented.  [See code](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-cache-redis/commit/19d6f909b52b5a437fc92d7c9b56ed54f4d9b9a5#diff-c2549d8c50355079220bd80dc833f2aaR128)

One option here is to disable via `BuildConfig`.  E.g. something like:

```
// ...
plugins {
    if (Environment.current == Environment.DEVELOPMENT) {
        // ... conditional parts for dev
    }
    // always...
}
```